# Convert Array to objects for Jsondata objects in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

Convert Array-String to Object with Javascript or jQuery

here is my array

```
data=["{X:7,Y:12.5}", "{X:8,Y:15}", "{X:9,Y:12.5}"]
```

expected output is object

```
data=[{X:7,Y:12.5},{X:8,Y:15},{X:9,Y:12.5}]
```

[image]

how to do that?

Comment: How do you end up with the objects in a stringified format? You would be better to change how you receive them instead of stringifying/parsing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = ["{X:7,Y:12.5}", "{X:8,Y:15}", "{X:9,Y:12.5}"];
data = data.join(',');
data = data.replace(/X/g,'"X"');
data = data.replace(/Y/g,'"Y"');
data = JSON.parse("["+data+"]");
```

Just convert array to string and do clean up that can be parsed to json.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
var data=["{X:7,Y:12.5}", "{X:8,Y:15}", "{X:9,Y:12.5}"];

data = data.map(function(item){
  item = item.replace(/{/g, "{\"");
  item = item.replace(/}/g, "\"}");
  item = item.replace(/:/g, "\":\"");
  item = item.replace(/,/g, "\",\"");
  return JSON.parse(item);
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Your answer is better :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to replace the X and Y with "X" & "Y". In order to create a string key that can be parse as JSON.

```
data=["{X:7,Y:12.5}", "{X:8,Y:15}", "{X:9,Y:12.5}"]

for(var i in data){
    tmp = data[i].replace("X",'"X"').replace('Y','"Y"')
    data[i] = JSON.parse(tmp)
}
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = /[^{,]+?(?=:)/g;
var data = ["{X:7,Y:12.5}", "{X:8,Y:15}", "{X:9,Y:12.5}"];
data = data.map(function(item){
    return JSON.parse(item.replace(reg, "\"$&\""));
});
```