# Remove quote from outside Json object in js

Tags: javascript, json

```
var obj = '{'include':true,'fn':'1-12'}'
```

I want to read fn value. how to remove single quotes which are present outside the {}?

Comment: JSON.parse will not work. It expects double quotes. These look like single quotes.

Comment: First of all, this is not a valid string.

Comment: I don't see double quotes

Comment: @OP, Where did the `obj` came from ? Did you try to make this on your own ?

Comment: You can check following [SO - post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650511/convert-array-to-objects-for-jsondata-objects-in-js/34650757?noredirect=1#comment57047834_34650757) for reference.

Comment: Object is a string? ```var x = eval("(" + obj + ")"); console.log(x.fn)```

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand, I think it a copy past problem... the quotes are probably  escaped in original code )

Comment: @tenbits removed my upper comment as I thought I was wrong there for a second but when running this line (the equivelant) I get a parse error myself: `var x = eval("('{'include':true,'fn':'1-12'}')"); console.log(x.fn)` so if the input is escaped as well it's not even close ;)

Comment: Why you need to remove quotes? You want to get the fn value rt?

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand, I mean, try in devconsole to write ```var str = "a\"b"```, then print str, press enter - you will see ```"a"b"```, so I think the code is copied from some similar place.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand, and you tried it not correct - it should be ```var x = eval("({'include':true,'fn':'1-12'})"); ```. ``obj`` is of type string. And the start-end quotes are not the part of the string

Comment: @tenbits oh dayum! That works really well and indeed I entered it wrong - my bad :S - Only one thing remains now which would be if the OP is receiving input from users or not which will define wether or not `eval` is safe to use, otherwise I think it's a good answer (and shouldn't be a comment instead of the other way around :P)

Answer (score 0):

try this

[remove double quotes from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156197/1075369)

like this:

```
var str = 'remove "foo" delimiting double quotes';
console.log(str.replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1'));
//logs remove foo delimiting quotes
str = 'remove only "foo" delimiting "';//note trailing " at the end
console.log(str.replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1'));
//logs remove only foo delimiting "<-- trailing double quote is not removed
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace single quotes `'` with double quotes `"` and then use `JSON.parse()` method to get a JSON object. The following works:

```
//var obj = '{'include':true,'fn':'1-12'}'; -- This assignment is invalid
var obj = "{'include':true,'fn':'1-12'}"; //Assuming double quotes outside
var obj1 = obj.replace(/'/g, "\""); //Replace single quotes with double quotes
console.log(typeof obj1); // string

var myjsonobj = JSON.parse(obj1); //convert to JSON

//myjsonobj is now a proper JSON object

console.log(myjsonobj); // Object {include: true, fn: "1-12"}
console.log(typeof myjsonobj); // object
console.log(myjsonobj.fn); // 1-12
```

Answer (score -1):

Here it works for you

```
var regex = /[\']/g;
var obj = "'{'include':true,'fn':'1-12'}'";
obj = obj.replace(regex,"");
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all this isn't valid JSON or javascript object

```
var obj = '{'include':true,'fn':'1-12'}'
```

Fix your object, then you can use `eval()`
like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"include":true,"fn":"1-12"}');
var fn = eval(obj.fn);
```